# Как вызвать метод из другой активити?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста как вызвать метод из другой активити?

Comment: Как правило, вызывать метод другой активити не нужно, так как активити, в данный момент не видимая на экране условно не существует, никаких действий выполнять не должна и отобразить их не сможет. Если вам требуется выполнить метод другой активити, то либо ваше приложение спроектировано неправильно, либо такой метод не должен находится в активити, поэтому будет лучше, если вы дополните вопрос и поясните, зачем вам это понадобилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй static.

В активите, у тебя есть следующий метод, который ты хочешь вызвать:

```
private static String name = "string_variable";

public static String getData() {
    return name;
}
```

И в вашем активите, где вы хотите сделать вызов:

```
private static String variable_string;

...

variable_string = AnotherActivity.getData();
```